# Spacing between li - how to remove?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

At [this site](http://charmcitykids.missionmedia.net/) and within the navigation are nav titles.  As you can see there is an unnecessary space between each nav title and I am stumped as to why this is.  Check out "classes," nav to get a good view of too much space.

I've been at this for a bit and to the point where I thought I'd ask around for a suggestion or tip.

Answer (score 4):

```
li {
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
```

And for another `<li>` vertical spacing adjustment option:

```
li {
  line-height:1.2em;
}
```

Look for anything involving `height` (i.e. line 324):

```
li, li a{
  height:32px;
}
```

*Note: I'm not sure what your* `xmargin` *or* `xheight` *in your CSS is for*

Comment: thanks ... i just found it.   Hidden away in the dropdown CSS was height: 52px

Comment: yeah i put x to blank/delete styles - may need to add them back later so just use x before any style